# Generate sparse matrix for a schrodinger operator on square grid

Tags: python, math, sparse-matrix

I am trying to generate a sparse matrix in SciPy to represent a Schrodinger operator on a sub grid of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. I originally tried to do so with NumPy but I encounter a memory allocation problem. I cannot think of how to implement this code without relying on NumPy first.

To clarify the problem, I want to generate an $N^2\times N^2$ symmetric matrix $H=A+D$, where $A$ is the adjacency on an $N\times N$ grid and $D$ is a diagonal matrix. My current implementation  for it (as pseudocode) is roughly as follows

```
    D = np.diag(arr)
    A = numpy.zeros( (N**2,N**2) )
    for i in range(N):
     for j in range(N):
      for k in range(N):   
       for l in range(N):
        if( abs(i-k)+abs(j-l)=1 ):
         A[i*N+j][k*N+l] =1

   H = A+D
```

But this code fails memory wise for my purposes. Is there a way to implement this sort of idea using the sparse package? I am especially having problems implementing the part regarding $A$ and then adding it to $D$. I think trying to implement the first part in NumPy will always fail.

I should mention that my coding skills are basic, so I'd appreciate even somewhat obvious feedback on code improvement.

Comment: Maybe use a function instead of storing the whole thing in memory. Something like AdjMat(x, y, N) then j = x % N, i = x / N, k = y % N, l = y / N and then if( abs(i-k)+abs(j-l)=1 ): return 1 else return 0.

Comment: Stack Overflow does not process any variant of TeX, so you should not use it unless it happens to be a question about TeX.

Answer (score 2):

With `lil_matrix` and `diags` from `scipy.sparse` you can create sparse matrices pretty efficiently.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix, diags

arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
N = len(arr)

np_arr = np.array(arr * N)
D = diags(np_arr, 0, format="lil")
A = lil_matrix((N**2, N**2))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k, l in [(i+1, j), (i-1, j), (i, j+1), (i, j-1)]:
            if 0 <= k < N and 0 <= l < N:
                A[i*N+j, k*N+l] = 1

A = A.tocsr()  # makes operations on sparse matrices more efficient
H = A + D
```

Comment: Generally it's faster, and more memory efficient to build `coo` style input arrays, but since this user is already setting elements iteratively, this `lil` approach is an easier sparse starting point.